# Why does react-router-dom not play well with my custom webpack, specifically not allowing for routes like `/story/:id`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom, create-react-app

Here is a link to a github repo I made if you wouldn't mind tinkering to see what you think..

https://github.com/williamowen65/DEMO--react-router-webpack--issue

The routes are declared on App.js. Just two routes. '/home' and '/story/:id'.

Home page displays while story page with a param doesn't. This setup would work via Create-React-App though.

Comment: Please add the code here, if you want fast answers to your problem. Links are not efficient way. Also try and add more information as much as possible e.g. if you are getting an error message, console log, etc...

Comment: In the webpack config try to add publicPath: '/' in output and check if that helps

Comment: @Soheb, THANK YOU! This fixed it! I am so grateful and will sleep a lot easier for it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code and run it. Everything is working for me.

#App#

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Story from "./pages/Story";

export default function App(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <h1>HELLO</h1>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path='/'
                    exact
                    element={<Home />}
                />
                <Route
                    path='/story/:id'
                    element={<Story />}
                />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

#Home#

```
import React from 'react';

function Home(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

#Story#

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Story(props) {
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Story: <span style={{color:"red"}}>{id}</span></h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Story;
```

Make Sure you send the **ID** through the URL like
**http://localhost:3000/story/123**

#Output#
[Click to See the Image of the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgjP7.png)